# How to capture change on page title from a Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, events, firefox-addon, dom-events

Is there a way to capture when a website title changes from a Firefox extension?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Do you mean changes of the title between two visits?

Comment: No, I mean when the title of a website changes without refreshing or anything like that. Like what happens with google instant search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know, if it works from a firefox extension, but as it works in a document, I think it works from a extension too.

You have to work with [Mutation-Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-MutationEvent), especially DOMSubtreeModified. This fires on every change on the target.

A little example-script, put it somewhere after the `<title/>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
(function()
  {
    var _this={
                target:document.getElementsByTagName('TITLE')[0],
                oldValue:document.title
              };
    _this.onChange=function()
                  {
                    if(_this.oldValue!==document.title)
                    {
                      _this.oldValue=document.title;
                      alert('somebody changed the title');
                    }
                 };
    _this.delay=function()
                {
                  setTimeout(_this.onChange,1);
                };
    _this.target.addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified',_this.delay,false)
  })()
//-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a [DOMTitleChanged](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Gecko-Specific_DOM_Events) event.

Comment: An example would have been helpful here.