# jQuery: "change" event on file input element does not fire if the file selection is triggered by an element other than the file input

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, events, file-io

RE:

- [Jquery: change event to input file on IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389341)
- [Any alternative to jQuery change() to detect when user selects new file via dialog box in IE8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993946)

---

The above questions dealt with getting the 'change' event to fire consistently across browsers after a file selection has been made. This is has been resolved as evidenced by the example at http://jsfiddle.net/7wR2L/

My situation is a tad different. It seems this issue rears its ugly head in another context.

Based on design constraints, I have to use a non-file-input element ('a' tag) to trigger the "click" event on the file input element. So far from my tests, it looks like the file input is unable to fire a "change" notification when a file is selected in this way.

Please take a look at the example at http://jsfiddle.net/rudylattae/7wR2L/8/

Test environment(s):

**Windows Server 2008 R2**

- Chrome 7.0.517.44 - PASS
- Firefox 3.6.9 - FAIL
- IE 8.0.7600.16385 64bit - FAIL

**Windows XP Pro (2002 - SP3)**

- Chrome 8.0.552.28 beta - PASS
- Firefox 3.5.14 - FAIL (does not even trigger the file selector)
- IE 8.0.6001.18702 - FAIL

Comment: Thanks to SO I woudln't have stumbled across this and would have continued laboriously, confident that I could make it work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With MSIE use the [onpropertychange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536956%28VS.85%29.aspx)-Event, example: http://jsfiddle.net/7wR2L/14/

As jQuery does'nt support this event you have to assign it without jquery(inline or use attachEvent )

In other browsers try using mutation-events, maybe they'll work there. See a related topic on mutation-events from yesterday, to have a little example how they work: [How to capture change on page title from a firefox extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4136453/how-to-capture-change-on-page-title-from-a-firefox-extension/4138892#4138892)

Comment: change is working fine. but in change event if I try to submit the form using `jQuery('#mediapicker #edit-submit').click();` the file field become empty and form not submitting. please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use modern version of *jQuery*.

Described problem with *change* event in Internet Explorer was fixed in **jQuery >= 1.6.4**.